# Android 4.4.2 escapes a specific azeri character "Ə" on specific android devices

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, localization

Android `4.4.2` escapes azeri character `Ə` from `BƏLİ` and other azeri words that uses this specific character. This issue comes on following device
Model:

> Huawei Honor V6, Version 4.4.2

I am using `BƏLİ` from localized `string.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <string name="lbl_okay">"BƏLİ "</string>
```

How can i resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably the device's font have no support for the specific character. You can try to test it by using a custom font in your app which has proper support for azeri characters.

Comment: @Alex i am using custom font already in my app. Surprisingly same font and same os version in LG devices shows doesn't escape the characters

Comment: I see. Usually the escaped square means that the font is missing that char. I had similar problems with older devices, but a custom font fixed that. Might be that your font is overwritten or clashing with a system font on that specific device. Who knows what modifications are made to the system by the device manufacturer.

Comment: Also maybe try to replace the problematic special char in the strings.xml with it's utf-8 unicode code \u018F who knows, might help

Comment: @Alex i tired adding unicode but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Then I guess it has to be the font. On my computer I can see correctly, but on the phone I see what I posted.

Comment: @Alex will try with some azeri fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I can't attach screenshot in comment so I will do it as an answer. I opened your question in the stackoverflow app and I couldn't see the char in the description, only in the title. See attached image. I am on android 8.1.0, nexus device.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. I'll try using unicode that you suggested then i will update you.